# No Ground Wire in Light Fixture Box

Tags: electrical, grounding

I am changing out my dimmer switch that has not worked in years. When I opened it I do not see where I can connect the dimmer box ground wire to anything. The dual switch next to the dimmer does not have a ground wire connected either. Is a ground wire needed. It looks like the previous person that installed the dimmer did not connect the dimmer ground wire to anything either.

Comment: Grounding is for your safety only.  The lack of grounding will not stop a circuit or parts(switches) from working.  It is possible you have metal conduit protecting the wires and that will be your ground or an old(1950s) house and have no ground.  The test for good ground is with a multi-meter and read ~120 volts between the hot/live(black US) wire and metal box.  If you have good ground, you can connect the ground wire to the box, or cap it or connect to box if no ground.

Comment: If the box has no ground, you have two options. (1) Bring in a ground by pulling a wire from a (hopefully nearby) box; or (2) live with it as it has been for 60+ years.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- Is a ground wire needed?

That depends on the switch specifications. Historically, ground wires were *not* required for simple switches. Some dimmers *may* require a ground wire - it should be in the installation instructions. Many *smart* switches (including "smart dimmers") require neutral and/or ground. Again, the installation instructions will make it clear. A switch could require neutral, ground, both or "one of the above" - it varies a lot.

- If a ground wire is needed, do you already have one and don't know it?

If you have metal boxes and metal conduit then you most likely have a valid ground path already and usually switches (and sometimes receptacles) can ground through their yokes to the metal box. So you *might* have ground and not even know it.

It is also possible to have metal boxes and ground wires with typical non-metallic (Romex) cables. The way it is supposed to be done is to bring the ground wire inside the box and screw it to the inside of the box. But sometimes in older installations the ground wire is left outside the box, either attached (not code-compliant, but functionally OK) or simply hanging. If you have cables and other things are grounded OK (e.g., grounded receptacles) then this is quite possible. Unfortunately, some extra work may be needed to find and fix the ground in this situation.